# A property about linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field.

Prove that if $L$ is any linear functional on $F[x]$ such that $L(fg)=L(f)L(g)$ for all $f$ and $g$,then either $L=0$ or there is a $t$ in $F$ such that $L(f)=f(t)$ for all $f$.

I attempted to prove the statement in this way:
Put $f=g=1$. Then $L(1)=L(1*1)=L(1)L(1)$.

Case 1

$L(1)=0$.

Then $L(f)=L(f)L(1)=0$ for all $f$. Thus $L=0$.

Case 2

$L(1) \ne 0$.

Then $L(1)=1$.

From here I got stuck. I have seen some similar situations in real valued functional equations before. Just don't know how to apply the method here.

Please give some help.
Thanks!

Best regards,Michael.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $t=L(x)$. You have shown that if $L\neq 0, L(1)=1$. Let $p=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ be a polynomial, you have $L(a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n)=L(a_0)+a_1L(x)+...+a_nL(x)^n$, since $L(1)=1$ you deduce that $L(p)=p(t)$.

Comment: ,Thank you very much! :).